Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate a component Filament Relation Manger
 Select::make('fees_description')
                ->label('الرسوم')
                ->preload()
                ->multiple()
                ->live()
                ->options(Fee::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                ->afterStateUpdated(function (Set $set, Get $get, $state) {
                    if (count($state)) {
                        $set('price', Fee::findMany($state)->sum('price'));
                        $set('sub_price', $this->getOwnerRecord()->addons()->sum('qty') * Fee::where('type', FeeTypeAttribute::MONTHLY->value)->findMany($get('fees_description'))->count());
                        $set('total', $get('price') + $this->getOwnerRecord()?->addons()->sum('qty') * Fee::where('type', FeeTypeAttribute::MONTHLY->value)->findMany($state)->count());
                    } else {
                        $set    ('price', 0);
                        $set    ('sub_price', 0);
                        $set    ('total', 0);
                    }
                }),

I have the following form in my relation manger in filament where i'm trying to update some fields base on the selected filed when ever i choose some Fees that are not monthly the component sends :
Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate a component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.

What is it i'm doing wrong?

In my case, the solution was to change public property to protected and then pass it to the Blade template manually. This way, it was excluded from Livewire's automatic handling under the hood.

This is inside a filmanet form not in livewire, so i don't have any public propery nor access to it
